# Header title paragraphs and misplaces itself

Tags: html, css

Previously, when my header only had 3 titles, i had no wrapping issues, however after adding another title, that specific title misplaces itself on top of the actual header.

Diagram of desired result: https://i.gyazo.com/3a71cc861daf2ec897cceed30d4bb576.png

Codepen: https://codepen.io/valik140795/pen/qadXOo

I believe the issue is coming from a dropdown button positioning(if not css), yet I am unable to specifically locate the issue.

Code of the button of the title that relocates itself:

```
<body>
<div class="body">
<div class="block_header">
  <div class="lang"><a href="updatethislinkforrussianversion">RU</a> | <a href="updatethislinkforenglishversion">ENG</a></div>
  <a href="index.html"><img src="pictures/logo.png" class="logo" width="220px;" /></a>


  <ul>
    <style>
      .dropbtn {
          background-color: #282828;
          color: #AA9568;
          padding: 0px;
          font-size: 16px;
          border: none;
          cursor: pointer;
      }

      .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
          background-color: #282828;
      }


      .dropdown {
          position: relative;
        z-index: 999;
          display: inline-block;
      }

      .dropdown-content {
          display: none;
          position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
          background-color: #282828;
          min-width: 180px;
          overflow: auto;
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      }

      .dropdown-content a {
          color: #AA9568;
          padding: 3px 5px;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
      }

      .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #282828}

      .show {display:block;}
    </style>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><a href=#fab>ФАБРИКИ</a></button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#nobilis">Nobilis</a>
        <a href="#colordeseda">Color de Seda</a>
        <a href="#eugenio">Eugenio Colombo</a>
        <a href="#libra">Libra</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      /* When the user clicks on the button,
      toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
      function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
      }

      function filterFunction() {
          var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
          input = document.getElementById("myInput");
          filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
          div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
          a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
          for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
              if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                  a[i].style.display = "";
              } else {
                  a[i].style.display = "none";
              }
          }
      }
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry but your HTML is all over the place, why do you have styles smack bang in the middle of an <ul> element? Also i'm pretty sure the only thing you can have within a <ul> element is an <li> element, so if you want to have divs within a list, you have to wrap them in a list element, same goes for lists within lists.

Comment: Fix your html and then move on from there

Comment: @DibsyJr, im a novice in coding, hence why i deemed it be more useful to have the script for the button wrapped around the button itself, since my css is like 500 lines, it is too confusing to include it there and maintain control over these elements. Same goes for you Pete

Comment: @Valbone by doing it in the manner you are, it is making it harder for you to see that you have orphaned html elements leading to invalid html.  I would recommend structuring your html and css properly, you will learn far faster and run into a lot less problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdown element that positions on top is out of the **ul** element that holds the other three, you should put it in the same parent container as them.